# Concatenating Date Time Records

Tags: sql-server

I have two variable 'Patient_FIN' and 'Date_Time'.  There are some a number of duplicate patient_fin. I would like to concatenate each unique patient fin into one row while also including each date_time variable.

```
 Example Data
 Financial Number     Requested 1 Date & Time
  1                2017-04-09 14:72:00.000
  1                2017-04-10 10:20:00.000
  2                2017-04-09 16:42:00.000
  3                2017-04-09 19:10:00.000
  4                2017-04-09 08:02:00.000
  4                2017-04-09 11:22:00.000
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
Financial Number     Requested 1 Date & Time1  Requested 1 Date & Time2
         1            2017-04-09 14:72:00.000      2017-04-10 10:20:00.00
         2            2017-04-09 16:42:00.000
         3            2017-04-09 19:10:00.000
         4            2017-04-09 08:02:00.000      2017-04-09 11:22:00.000
```

I attempted to use the following code but its putting date_time into one column when there are duplicate FINS.

```
 SELECT [Financial Number], [Requested 1 Date & Time] =
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '   '  +[Requested 1 Date & Time]
         FROM [ED_Dispo_Events_Using_Event_1 Triage Level 3] b 
         WHERE b.[Financial Number] = a.[Financial Number] 
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
 FROM [ED_Dispo_Events_Using_Event_1 Triage Level 3] a
 Group BY [Financial Number]
```

Comment: Is there only 1 pair of duplicates for each [Financial Number]?

Comment: Your output doesn't look like you're concatenating the values; that looks like a second column. Which ar eyou actualy after?

Comment: @Larnu, the output option above is the preferred choice but if it's not possible, concatenation would suffice.

Comment: Can I *assume* that if a patient had a 3rd time, you'd want a 3rd column? What is the limit of times a single patient can have?

Comment: @forpas there are 3-4 duplicate FINs at times

Comment: What is the "time" "14:72"??

Comment: sorry, that should be '14:52' an error on my part in attempting to randomize the sample data date/times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the maximum rows is 4, (and the "time" `14:72` is a typographical error) you can use a "cross tab" to achieve this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT FinancialNumber,
           RequestedDateTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.FinancialNumber ORDER BY RequestedDateTime) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES (1,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-09T14:22:00.000')),
                 (1,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-10T10:20:00.000')),
                 (2,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-09T16:42:00.000')),
                 (3,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-09T19:10:00.000')),
                 (4,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-09T08:02:00.000')),
                 (4,CONVERT(datetime,'2017-04-09T11:22:00.000'))) V(FinancialNumber,RequestedDateTime))
SELECT C.FinancialNumber,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN RequestedDateTime END) AS RequestedDateTime1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN RequestedDateTime END) AS RequestedDateTime2,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN RequestedDateTime END) AS RequestedDateTime3,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN RequestedDateTime END) AS RequestedDateTime4
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.FinancialNumber;
```

Comment: thanks so what I shared is sample data-I have thousands of records. How does that impact your answer above as I can't convert each an every datetime?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here @Greg. 1, or 1 Million rows won't change the answer above. The only reason I have a `CONVERT` is because I used a literal string for the sample data.

Comment: @Greg `VALUES` is your sample data. You wouldn't have that in your statement, as you have your table; I don't have have access to it so I can't use it. Perhaps that's what you're misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution using [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
SELECT fin, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM (
    SELECT fin, date_col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fin ORDER BY fin, date_col) AS rn
    FROM test
) st PIVOT (  
    MAX(date_col)
    FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS pt;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbbc3743328dedae8d4561878895939c)

**Note:** This solution supports a financial number with up to four date values. In case you want to support more date values per financial number you have to add more columns (`[5], [6], ...`) to the `SELECT` and `PIVOT`.